# AVFoundation barcode scanner detecting AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject vs AVMetadataFaceObject

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, barcode-scanner

Compiling on Swift 2.0, running IOS 9.3 working with Xcode 7.2.1 under 10.11.3

Trying to implement a code 39 bar code scanner, but unable to figure how to cast this without crashing my code in the process, unless I use this hack.

AVFoundation returns both AVMetadataFaceObject & AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject objects when scanning my bar code.

If I try and cast the wrong object into the wrong type it crashes, and for the life of I can not seem to find a way of figuring out which type of code it is looking at beyond this hack.

Tried guard statement; no crash. Tried do/catch; no crashes. Tried to test the type, but nothing seems to work.

```
if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
        //print("No code is detected")
        return
    } else {
        let A1 = String(metadataObjects[0])
        if (A1.hasPrefix("<AVMetadataFaceObject:")) {
            print("Face -> \(A1)")
        }
        if (A1.hasPrefix("<AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject:")) {
            let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            self.lblDataInfo.text = metadataObj.stringValue
            self.lblDataType.text = metadataObj.type
            print("Machine -> \(A1) ")
        }
    }
```

Ok, this works, but I don't think its good coding practice, I fear it is hack.

Comment: Have you found any other solution? this is working fine for you?

Comment: Hi Mac, I want with this works reasonably well.